# joining 3 tables sql join

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have 3 tables `users(name, email), reviews(review, entity, user) and votes(vote, entity, user)`, I want to make a query which returns all the reviews given for a particular entity, and vote from votes table if the user have voted for that entity, else null should be there at the place of vote. The query I wrote is

```
select users.name as name, 
reviews.review as review, 
votes.vote as vote 
from 
users join reviews on users.email=reviews.user 
left join votes on users.email=votes.user 
where reviews.entity='entity_id'
```

But this query is resulting multiple rows for some reviews, 
I made it working using group by, by am unable to understand the behavior of left join,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not joining votes for any specific entity, try the following:

```
select users.name as name, 
reviews.review as review, 
votes.vote as vote 
from 
users join reviews on users.email=reviews.user 
left join votes on users.email=votes.user and reviews.entity = votes.entity
where reviews.entity='entity_id'
```

Comment: Remember group by clause as OP says: "But this query is resulting multiple rows for some reviews, I made it working using group by..."

Comment: I would have to see the working version, but I doubt the results would be correct by adding a group by. The query would still be looking for reviews with the entity 'entity_id', but votes for any entity from the same user.